# Partial derivative of composite function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Given, 
\begin{align}
f(x, y, z) & = x^{2} \times y \times 2z \tag{1}\\
g(f(x, y, z), a) & = f(x, y, z) \times a \tag{2}\\
h(g(f(x, y, z),a)) & = g(f(x, y, z), a) - 1 \tag{3}
\end{align}

How to find $\dfrac{\partial h(g(f(x, y, z),a)) }{\partial x}$?

**My answer**: 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial h(g(f(x, y, z),a)) }{\partial x} & = a \times 2xy \times 2z
\end{align}

Would you be so nice and let me know if I got the correct answer?

Comment: Please considering writing in latex. And your notation is very awkward.

Comment: Also, you seem to have forgotten the minus sign in your answer.

Comment: Yes I know, I am not a mathematician. This is the best I can. But is good, the result?

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous, so it is not possible to say if your result is correct. We can try to interpret it. For instance, you defined $f$ three times, and then ask for $F$ which is not defined.

Comment: I named all functions with I, II, III. and I am looking of partial derivative III/x

Comment: @Testingman I have edited your post heavily, so please confirm if this is correct!

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. You can further simplify it as $4 a xyz$.

Comment: @NashJ. Thank you Nash. For your reply and your edit. I think I understand now how mathematicians define and prepare everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$h(g(f(x, y, z),a))=2ax^2yz-1$$

and indeed

$$\frac{\partial h(g(f(x, y, z),a))}{\partial x}=4axyz.$$